# jQuery select by input name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input:

```
<tr><td class="forms">Price:</td><td><input type="text" name="price" size="30"/></td></tr>
```

How can I call this input?

Example: With this code I call to the id:

```
$("#numberclasses").change(function() {
```

And I call to the class with this:

```
$(".numberclasses").change(function() {
```

But How can I call to the name?

Comment: what is numberclasses here?

Comment: @ryadavilli does it matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
$('input[name="price"]').change(function() {
```

Check out the [jQuery selectors docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more info.

Comment: missing quotes? `input[name="price"]`

Comment: This is true, however [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) show with the quotes in the format `jQuery( "[attribute='value']" )` so I suppose it's best to follow suit

Comment: @TomWalters I did not say to follow W3Schools!! ;D just talking from experience. Kidding, Sure, let's follow the DOCS. always.

Comment: @roXon maybe one day you will be able to use selector like `$('input[name=value]')` ;)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski no, unless you excape the `' quotes '`. That's why you're perfectly able to "miss" the quotes.

Comment: @roXon I rarely use the quotes myself, but the jQuery docs are so new and shiny its hard to disagree with them!

Comment: @TomWalters HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAH TOM ! you made my day! +10 to your answer! I almost killed my self with my coffee