# how can I change the style of each element by name?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I would like to change all elements, that have the name "hiddenElement" with jquery

alle elements should get the style

```
style.display='none';
style.position='absolute';
```

How is the syntax in jquery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/1107220/1771795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
$("[name='hiddenElement']").hide().css("position", "absolute");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  $("[name='hiddenElement']").hide().css("position","absolute");
```

Comment: This will hide all Div's with that name...

Comment: Actually somebody edited while I was editing

Comment: @Ankit Not blaming you but...I was editing at the same time you were editing so my edit was not saved first time.

Answer (score 1):

You use `[attribute=value]` to select matching elements

```
$(*[name=hiddenElement]).css({'display':none,'position':'absolute'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe "name" should be unique(unless your talking about radio buttons). Do you mean "class"?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hiddenElement').css({'display':'none','position':'absolute'});
});
```