# Select dom elements by attributes having array like attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many elements that are structured to get them in array like mapping on server side.

```
<input type="CHECKBOX" id="478" value="1" name="data[GroupInfo][student][478]" onclick="return updateValues('478')">
<input type="CHECKBOX" id="490" value="1" name="data[GroupInfo][student][490]" onclick="return updateValues('490')">

<input type="CHECKBOX" id="478" value="1" name="data[ClassInfo][student][478]" onclick="return updateValues('478')">
<input type="CHECKBOX" id="490" value="1" name="data[ClassInfo][student][490]" onclick="return updateValues('490')">
```

so on...
Now, I want to select them using their name attribute like

```
$("[name^=data[ClassInfo][student]]");
```

but this won't work 
I tried to escape barckets to.

```
$("[name^=data\[ClassInfo\]\[student\]]");
```

but no luck;

I want to select them using name attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the attribute value in `""`

```
$('input[name^="data[ClassInfo][student]"]')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/svWsz/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// For exact element
    $('input[name=data[GroupInfo][student][478]]');
```

Or

```
// For list of elements
    $('input[name^=data[GroupInfo][student]]');
```

You can see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[name^='data[ClassInfo][student]']");//Wrap in the single quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name*="data[ClassInfo][student]"]') // matches those that contain 'data[ClassInfo][student]'
```