# JQuery how to get the object with selector?

Tags: jquery

In JQuery , how to get the object of 'name' input with selector ? like

$("#myform>name")

```
<form id='myform'>
   <input name='name' type='text' />
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#myform > input[name='name']")
```

or use direct by attribute selector if there is only element with this attribute value combination:

```
$('input[name="name"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$('#myform > input[name="name"]')
```

There are other ways too but this is exactly what you asked 
about (it selects all input elements with name `name` which 
are below `myform` in the DOM tree).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute selector like so:

```
$('input[name="name"]');
```