# How can i get the values out of multiple html form elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a test and I'm trying to get the values associated with each answer so i can give the user a score based on those values.  Right now the code gives me double the answers worth.  Right now there are 7 questions and each time the user clicks the radio button with the right answer it should be worth 1 point. At the end when I submit test it seems as if all the values were doubled(getting a 200% when i only got 100%).  Any help is appreciated.

Here is my test:

```
<ol>
<li>What are the three main areas of the Standard User Interface?
  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  />Header, Banner, Frame, Application Window</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Content Frame, Homepage, Form </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()"/> Application Navigator, Banner Frame, Content Frame </li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"  /> Larry, Moe, and Curly</li>
  </ul>
 </li>

<li>In the User interface, what is the gray toolbar called which allows you to add bookmarks?

  <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Gauge</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()"/> Edge</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Remedy</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0" /> Banner</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>What can be captured in an update set?

   <ul type="none">
     <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> Modified CI Rules</li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()"/> Business Rules</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> Scheduled Jobs</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0" /> None of these</li>
  </ul>
</li>

 <li>What should you always do before you commit an update set?

   <ul type="none">
     <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()" /> Preview</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="0"  /> Merge</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="0"  /> Ignore</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="0"  /> All of these</li>
   </ul>
 </li>

 <li>Which of the following is a Business Rule best pratice?

   <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()" /> Make business rules small and specific</li>

     <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="0"  /> Use of conditions is not necessary</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="0"  /> Global business rules should be used</li>

    <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="0"  /> None of these</li>
  </ul>
 </li>

 <li>Which of the following is a Client Script best practice?

   <ul type="none">
    <li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="0"  /> Use hard coded data</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="0"  /> Maximize server lookup</li>
 <li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()" /> Do not use g_form.getReference()</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="q6" value="0"  /> All of these</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>Which of the following are debugging features?

 <ul type="none">
 <li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="0"  /> Debug Business Rule</li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="0"  /> Javascript</li
     <li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="1" onchange="checkAnswer()" /> Debug Business Rule and Javascript</li>
     <li><input type="radio" name="q7" value="0"  /> There is none</li>

      </ul>
</li>


</ol>




<button onclick="finishTest()"> Submit Test  </button>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var question=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var grade;
var score = 0;
var totalQuestions = 7;
function checkAnswer(){
    for(var questionNum = 0; questionNum<totalQuestions; questionNum++){
        var answer = question[questionNum].value;
        if(answer=="1"){
            score+=1;

        }else{
            score+=0;
        }

        grade = "%" + (score/totalQuestions)*100;
    }
}
function finishTest(){

    alert(" You scored a " +grade);

}
```

Comment: You are not even considering the values of radio buttons

Comment: So i should put buttons instead?

Comment: Check  my code below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Comment: im not even using JQuery why did this get voted down :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function instead

```
function finishTest()
{
var score = 0;
var maxQues = 7;
for(var questionNum = 1; questionNum<=maxQues; questionNum++){
var radios = document.getElementsByName('q'+questionNum);
for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked && radios[i].value=="1") score++; 

}
}
    score = parseFloat(score*100/maxQues).toFixed(1);
    alert("You scored "+score+"%");
}
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/kvhcv60h/5/)**

Comment: Yea this took up less space and worked better i suck lol. Thank you for your help!