# Dynamically populate the drop down for dynamically created elements in the form

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
function flavorDefn(e) {
            var locationid = $(e).attr('id');

            var idArray = locationid.split('-');
            var id = idArray[1];
            var flavorDef="flavorDefs"+id;
             $("#"+flavorDef).prop("disabled", true);
            $.getJSON('flavorDefinitions.wss', {
                location : $(this).val(),
                ajax : 'true'
            }, function(data) {
                $("#"+flavorDef).prop("disabled", false);
                var html = '';
                var len = data.length;
                for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id+ '" id="'+data[i].id+'">'
                            + data[i].cpus+' CPU '+data[i].ram+' MB RAM '+data[i].disk+' GB DISK '+ '</option>';
                }
                html += '</option>';
                $("#"+flavorDef).html(html);
            });
        }

<select name="locationName" id="location-<%=patternBO.getId()%>" onchange="flavorDefn(this)">
<select name="flavorDefs" id="flavorDefs<%=patternBO.getId()%>">
```

In the form there are 2 drop down which are created dynamically after the page loads. I have written a jquery function which will be called when 1st drop down value changes. But when I try to access the dynamically created form field value it says TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined.

Comment: Did u try to figure out the line flavorDefn function beyond which control does not propagate. As a JAVA developer not well acquainted with front end development i suggest printing all values in console.log or for quick debug put an alert after every line(not a good way of debugging though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(){
    $('select[name="locationName"]').change(function(){
        var theValue = this.value;
        $('select[name="flavorDefs"]').val(theValue);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgx89twt/)

---

If the select is populated after the DOM is initially rendered, you can use event delegation to catch the event:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name="locationName"]', function(){
        var theValue = this.value;
        $('select[name="flavorDefs"]').val(theValue);
    });
});
</script>
```

Reference:

http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

[How can I select an element by name with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Comment: hi Gibberish ,
Did you notice that I am looking for calling a function on the elements which are created when the form is loaded . Please look at the code
id="location-<%=patternBO.getId()%>" this id value will be populated after the form is loaded

Comment: Please see revised answer. *I recommend against inline js code - poor design, difficult to troubleshoot later on down the road.*

Comment: Thanks  a lot @gibberish. The suggestion worked. If not through the js code then How can it be achieved ?

Comment: `Inline` code (bad) is where you embed javascript into the HTML tags, such as: `<input onclick="someFunction();">`, whereas external code (good) is contained within `<script> your code goes here </script>` tags. [Reference1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138884/when-should-i-use-inline-vs-external-javascript), [Reference 2](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting)

Comment: You might find Alex Garrett's (free) video courses to be helpful: http://phpacademy.org -and- [theNewBoston.com](https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32)