# Unable to set TextArea value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am only setting one simple value in text area using jquery on radio button click. but it sets nothing.

**My Code is:**

```html
Javascript
---------
$("input[name=radio_workitem]").on("change",function(){

   $("input[name='workItemVO.note']",'#id_form_workitem_view').val("dummyNote");
}


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <input type="radio" name="radio_workitem" value="<s:property value="workItemId"/>">

    <s:form id="id_form_workitem_view">
        <s:textfield name="workItemVO.subject" id="id_txt_wi_subject" class="form-control" readonly="true" />
        <s:textfield  name="workItemVO.createdBy" class="form-control" readonly="true"/>

        <s:textarea name="workItemVO.note"  class="form-control" rows="4"></s:textarea>
```

### What I have Tried:

```html
$("input[name='workItemVO.note']",'#id_form_workitem_view').html("dummyNote");
$("input[name='workItemVO.note']",'#id_form_workitem_view').text("dummyNote")
```

**Doesn't work.**

**Here: if I set value using text area id, it works properly
example: $("#Note").val("dummyNote"); // works fine**

But I want to use "Name" not "Id"

Plz help, i am very new in Stack overflow, may be some mistake in my description. Plz let  me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery meaby you should use $("textarea[name=workItemVO.note]", ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input[name='workItemVO.note'] //this won't work because textArea is not an input
```

use `textarea` instead of `input`

```
$("textarea[name='workItemVO.note']").val('dummyNote')
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/3npr0kkp/)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! More over for your quick reply.!! it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`<textarea/>` is not an `<input/>`.

You can use the `:input` selector, or simply specify `textarea[name="..."]`

Your on change listener is missing a `)` at the end, but I assume that's a copy and paste error.

Provided that `<s:textarea/>` does indeed render as a textarea with the name intact [your code will work if you use the `textarea` selector](http://jsfiddle.net/gmx2rkv9/).