# Is it possible to get onclick value by input name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get on click value by input name in jQuery? I don't have neither class nor id and I want to get the on click value on name only. As I am doing all this in a software to get data.

```
<input type="button" name="view" value="Click To View Phone, Mobile &amp; Fax Numbers" onclick="viewphone(71241,'divid71241')">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , it is easy to get onclick value

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>


<input type="button" name="view" value="Click To View Phone, Mobile &amp; Fax Numbers" onclick="viewphone(71241,'divid71241')" style="border: 0px;">

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name=view]').click(function(){
     var valueis = $(this).attr('onclick');
     alert(valueis);
    });
   });


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `attribute selector`

For example for your element

```
<input type="button" name="view" value="Click To View Phone, Mobile &amp; Fax Numbers" onclick="viewphone(71241,'divid71241')" style="border: 0px;">
```

If you just have one element with a unique name:

```
$("input[name='view']").click(function() {
// function data goes here 
console.log( this.value )
});
```

If you have multiple elements with the same name you can use the `each() method`

```
$("input[name='view']").each(function() {
// function data goes here 
console.log( this.value )
});
```

**Output**

```
Click To View Phone, Mobile & Fax Numbers
// other input values here
```

If you have multiple elements with the same name but only want the first ones value you can use the `.first()` method:

```
$("input[name='view']").first(function() {
// function data goes here 
console.log( this.value )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**yes use the following**

```
onclick="viewphone(71241,'divid71241',this.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I believe you can use attr name to trigger an event.

```
$('input[name=view]').click(function(){
    // functions here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do that by using [attribute] selector .

```
input[name="view"]
```

will select that particular Element.

```
$('input[name="view"]').click(function(){

});
```

Here is a reference link :
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/