# Can I use jquery to operate the name attribute of <a> tag？

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web I have more than 5 links,some of them are in the same group. I want to make them hide or show together.So I give the same name to the common link.But How to operate them?

```
<a href='a.jsp' name='group1'>aa</a>
<a href='b.jsp' name='group2' >bb</a>
<a href='c.jsp' name='group1'>cc</a>
<a href='d.jsp' name='group2'>dd</a>
<a href='e.jsp' name='group1'>ee</a>
```

If use input,I can write like `$("input[name='group1']").hide();`.But now is link tag.How to operate them?

Comment: Have you tested it? You have all informations in your question. Just change `input` with `a`. `$("a[name='group1']").hide();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Comment: When you have `<input>` elements, you write `$("input[name='group1']")`. What would you write when you have `<a>` elements...? That said, it's more common to use classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classes are our friend - forget trying to use a name attribute - this is not the correct use for that. What you want to do is add a class and then alter the display based on the class:

```
//HTML
<a href='a.jsp' class='group1'>aa</a>
<a href='b.jsp' class='group2' >bb</a>
<a href='c.jsp' class='group1'>cc</a>
<a href='d.jsp' class='group2'>dd</a>
<a href='e.jsp' class='group1'>ee</a>

//js
$('.group1').hide();
```

you can also add css in the jquery

```
//js
$('.group1').css('display','none');
```

but the better way of altering the display state is to have a class that you then add or remove to the elements - that way you are not altering the actual css of the element:

```
//css
.hidden {display:none}
.shown{display:block}

//js


$('.group1').addClass('hidden');
```

you can also toggle the class - which allows you to show the elements simply by not hiding them
//js

```
 $('.group1').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of the anchor tags with this the same code as you would use for input, but you just specify that you want to select the `<a>` tags, and then you can call the method hide().

```
$("a[name='group1']").hide()
```

The `[name='name']` part of the code is called CSS attribute selector, and it can be used with most HTML tags.

See this:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

And this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Although when doing something like this, it would be much better to use classes.