# Set textbox value by array index and name attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

$("[name=imageheight]") return following array of textboxes

[image]

I know i can get the value of textbox by its index like

[image]

How do i set the value of textbox on index 0. i have tried this but it gives me a error

[image]

Comment: `$('[name=imageheight]').eq(0).val()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery

Comment: thanks @guradio.. $('[name=imageheight]').eq(0).val() run without any error but $("[name=imageheight]") still return "
[<input id=​"2793497" type=​"number" name=​"imageheight" value=​"175">​,<input id=​"4346700" type=​"number" name=​"imageheight" value=​"175">​]"

Comment: can you update the OP so it is more clear what is still the problem

Comment: $('[name=imageheight]').eq(0).attr('value', '250') its working for me. Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('input').eq(0).val("new value")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, no explaination and I don't see the problem solve and make me confused.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[name=imageheight]').eq(0).attr('value', '250')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('[name=imageheight]').eq(0).val(250)
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation:

jQuery returns a jQuery object which has a val function, which returns its value if no parameter is passed and sets its value if a parameter is passed. However, the [0] of a jQuery object is an element and is not a jQuery object. As a result, it does not have a val() function. You can work with that as well, if you set its value attribute, like this:

jQuery("input[name=firstname]")[0].value = 250;
Also, you can bypass jQuery if you want, like this:

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=firstname]")[0].value = 250;

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, `$("[name=imageheight]")[0]` will not return an jQuery object. So you **cannot** use `.val()` over that node. But, `$("[name=imageheight]").eq(0)` will return the node as a jQuery object over which you can use `.val()`

```js
$('input').eq(0).val("new value")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually $("[name=imageheight]") returns jquery object of that element. that jquery object contains javascript DomElement object you can access DomElement object from jQuery object by `$('....')[0]`

`$("[name=imageheight]")[0].value` obviously return value because value is propert of DomElement.

You can set value by `$("[name=imageheight]")[0].value= 250;` in DomElement object

val() is setter and getter method of jQuery you have to fetch first element onlu by `.first()` method or `':first'` selector.

`$("[name=imageheight]:first").val(250);`

or

`$("[name=imageheight]").first().val(250);`