# Convert and add a collection of div values to Integers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have various rating values on a page; I want to get the average rating, however, what I thought would work is not so far.

```
<div class = "ratings">1</div>
<div class = "ratings">5</div>
<div class = "ratings">3</div>
<div class = "ratings">2</div>
```

I want to sum these ratings and find the average.

```
function overallRating()
{
       var items = document.getElementsByClassName("ratings");
       var itemCount = items.length;
       var sum= 0;

       for(var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
       {
            sum += parseInt(items[i].value);
            console.log(sum)
       }
}
```

The console log of `sum` returns `NaN`.

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: why would this question get closed? and how does this question lead to -- _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error._ . ?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw  Every user can do as they please with their "vote". Logically, it does not. It could perhaps be argued that `.textContent` for `.value` substitution is negligible. The total omission of average of `sum` being returned cannot logically be proven to be a problem that would be corrected by a continuing to omit returning the average of `sum`.

Comment: @guest271314 _Every user can do as they please with their "vote"_ not really, there should be a **valid** reason to do so not because of _as they please with their "vote"_.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Well, that clearly is not the case. "should be" does not exist. "valid" as to evaluation of a "vote" should be limited to whether the "vote" was allowed in the first instance, and "free" in the second instance.

Comment: @guest271314 guess I will have to fight the case if "closed" to get it reopened and will have to stress this to the meta site **again**. close votes should be taken seriously and **not** _as they please with their "vote"_.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Good luck at meta. The proof of reasons selected not being logically  applicable are at first comment above.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Needs more "downvote" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103717/on-click-get-input-value-using-jquery/43103840#43103840, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663975/checking-for-an-empty-string-array/43664408#43664408

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw It must be noted that logic is not the barometer for impetus or reason for user action at SO. Obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div`'s don't have a property called `value` (only `input`s does). Use `textContent` instead. Change this:

```
sum += parseInt(items[i].value);
```

to this:

```
sum += parseInt(items[i].textContent);
```

Comment: OP also asked for average of `sum`

Comment: @guest271314 I bet OP already knows how to calculate the average.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to use `textContent` to retrieve the text of the `div`.

```
sum += parseInt(items[i].textContent);
```

to retrieve the average simply, insert the code below after the for loop.

```
return sum / itemCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerText` instead of `.value`, and trim before use ;)

```
 sum += parseInt(items[i].innerText.trim());
```

```js
function overallRating() {
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName("ratings");
  var itemCount = items.length;
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(items[i].innerText.trim());
    console.log(sum)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ratings">1</div>
<div class="ratings">5</div>
<div class="ratings">3</div>
<div class="ratings">2</div>
<input type='submit' onClick='overallRating(this)' />
```