# Get value from input field with jQuery

Tags: jquery, shopify

i would like to get the value from an input field. 
The code looks like this:

```
<input type="number" step="any" 
name="properties[wallpaper_size_width]" class="spb-productdescfont 
spb-productoptiontextcolor spb-productoptionbackground" 
placeholder="Breite in cm" required="">
```

Because I dont have an id for that input

```
$("#height").value();
```

will not work. I confused by the [] @name=

How can I select the value by the name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Comment: try this `$("[name='properties[wallpaper_size_width]']").value(); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `name` selector like this,

```js
$('.getVal').click(function(){
   var value = $("[name='properties[wallpaper_size_width]']").val();
   console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" step="any" 
name="properties[wallpaper_size_width]" class="spb-productdescfont 
spb-productoptiontextcolor spb-productoptionbackground" 
placeholder="Breite in cm" required="">

<button class='getVal'>Click me</button>
```