# jQuery Set Select options from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a simple search for my application and am wondering if there is way to dynamically set the values of forms based on JSON

I send a query to the API which returns a bit of JSON along with the results which indicates what the filtered dropdown boxes should be. So for example, if I'm searching for cars and in the make, I select 'Ford' this is what a typical response would look like to indicate what the other dropdown fields should look like:

```
{
  "make": [
    "Ford"
  ],
  "model": [
    "ECOSPORT",
    "Fiesta",
    "Focus",
    "Transit"
  ],
  "colour": [
    "Blue",
    "White",
    "Red",
    "Black"
  ],
  "fuel": [
    "Petrol",
    "Diesel"
  ],
  "transmission": [
    "Manual"
  ],
  "bodystyle": [
    "Suv",
    "Hatchback",
    "Bus"
  ],
  "engine": [
    998,
    1498,
    1242,
    1499,
    2198
  ],
  "door": [
    5,
    3
  ],
  "interior": [
    "Part leather",
    "Not set",
    "Cloth"
  ],
  "age": [
    "2016",
    "2017",
    "2011"
  ]
}
```

The original query is also returned which looks like this, (it could have multiple if more than one option was selected for the original query, for example, make and model)

```
[
  {
    "name": "make",
    "value": "Ford"
  }
]
```

What I'm looking to do is loop through the first JSON which contains the dropdown filters and loop through each form element (by name) and update the value (Except for the one in the original query, so in this case the make)

The form elemets input names match the names returned by the query:

```
                       <select name="make">
                            <option value="">Make (All)</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col span_2_of_12">
                        <select name="model"> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                 <select name="transmission"></select>
```

In this example, I would like the code to add options to the select for 'model' and 'transmission' whilst not updating the values for 'make' as that was in the original query

I've tried to do it as a loop but it doesn't seem to do anything

```
      var dropdown = data.dropdown;
      $.each(dropdown, function (key, value) {
        var item = $("input[name=" + key + "]")
        item.empty()
        $.each(value, function (x, y) {
          item.append(new Option(y + ' (All)', ""));
          item.append("<option value=" + y + ">" + y + "</option>");
        });
      });
```

Comment: your code can be reduced if you can tell, you are using jquery select menu. There are in build functions to initialize the options. you will be using jquery-ui js for it. If that is the case then i can post the solution

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma - I'm not using jquery-ui currently, but if it makes it easier to do this them I'm open to using it

Comment: What you used so far should also work, just thought about that. Including JQUERY-UI just for this functionality doesn't make sense. What is not working when you debug this code? any error?

Comment: The issue appears to be selecting the 'select' element by name. doing `$('input[name=model]').empty()` doesn't work but then if i assign an id to the element and do `$('#model').empty()` it empties it - not sure why it's not workign when selecting by name?

Comment: well, there is a chance that selecting element with name in jquery is wrong in your code. can you try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery you need to be careful with " (quotes)

Comment: Changing the selector to  $("#vehicle-search [name=" + key + "]") has worked it now clears the select options and populates them with the correct list, just need to compare the keys against the original query to not update the make dropdown for example when it was in the original query