# Check a checkbox (having just type and name) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this checkbox that has ONLY `type` and `name` attributes. I cannot add `className` or `id` to it.

How can I check/uncheck this checkbox using jQuery?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="savedCcCheckbox">
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I select an element by name with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107220/how-can-i-select-an-element-by-name-with-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  Wasn't asking how to SELECT an element, was asking how to MANIPULATE it.  Answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$('[name=savedCcCheckbox]').prop( "checked", true );